# What does "cock an eyebrow" actually mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is [The Free Dictionary's definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cock) of the word "cock" :)

3. To tilt or turn up or to one side, usually in a jaunty or alert manner: **cocked an eyebrow** in response to a silly question.

Can "cock an eyebrow" can mean the same as "raise an eyebrow" or does this phrase convey strictly that it moves to the side?  (as far as I know, turn up doesn't mean to raise)

Comment: I can tilt my head sideways (cock my head), but I can't move my eyebrows sideways.

Comment: 'Turn up to one side' means that one side bends or tilts upwards, not that it moves sideways.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cock?locale=en) has ***cock one's eye** Glance in a quizzical or knowing manner with a raised eyebrow.*

Answer (score 4):

[image: The People's Eyebrow] Nope, cock here means to tilt as if you're suspicious or unimpressed as opposed to simply raising them like you might when surprised.

Comment: I mean form me he is raising he's right eyebrow =P Also, moving my eyebrow to the side seems like an impossible task :D

Comment: He is raising one eyebrow. Though he's pulling down towards the middle of the forehead. This sort of tilts it rather than raising the whole thing up.

Comment: Also don't raise your brows sideways. That sounds dangerous.

Comment: The question wasn't about raising both eyebrows, which I agree denotes surprise. Is raising *just one eyebrow* different from *cocking an eyebrow*? I feel they're the same